# How to add a string to JSON list in python

Tags: python, json, string, api

Here is my code sample:

```
    try: 
        REST_Call = Session.get(CC_URL_REST) #Getting the session for a particular url.
        REST_CALL = REST_Call.content #Retrieving the contents from the url.
        JSON_Data = json.loads(REST_CALL) #Loading data as JSON.
        Report_JSON.append(JSON_Data) #Appending the data to an empty list
```

The JSON data that is returned and appended to the 'Report_JSON' is:

```
             [
               {
                  "content": [
                     {
                        "id": 001,
                        "name": "Sample_Name",
                        "description": "Sample_description",
                        "status": "STARTED",
                        "source": null,
                        "user": "username"
                     }
                },
              ],
```

I just want to add the below data in string format to the above JSON list:

```
{
    "CronExpression": "0 1,30 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 ? * 2,3,4,5,6"
},
```

Sample code for the above string data:

```
        Cron_Call = Session.get(Cron_URL_REST)
        Cron_CALL = Cron_Call.content
        Cron_Data = json.loads(Cron_CALL)
        cron_value = Cron_Data["cronExpression"] 

        Report_JSON.append({
                    "CronExpression": cron_value
        })
```

When trying to append it to the 'Report_JSON' this is the output I get:

```
             [
               {
                  "content": [
                     {
                       "id": 001,
                       "name": "Sample_Name",
                       "description": "Sample_description",
                       "status": "STARTED",
                       "source": null,
                       "user": "username"
                     }
                },
              ],
              {
              "CronExpression": "0 1,30 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 ? * 2,3,4,5,6"
              },
```

I'm trying to show both the data's under the same "content" tab unlike it being separate.

This is the result i'm trying to get:

```
       {
            "id": 001,
            "name": "Sample_Name",
            "description": "Sample_description",
            "status": "STARTED",
            "source": null,
            "user": "username"
            "CronExpression": "0 1,30 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 ? * 2,3,4,5,6"
        },
```

Any ideas on how to implement it?

Comment: Can you show what you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over `JSON_Data['content']` and add the new key to each of them.

```
Cron_Call = Session.get(Cron_URL_REST)
Cron_CALL = Cron_Call.content
Cron_Data = json.loads(Cron_CALL)
cron_value = Cron_Data["cronExpression"] 
for x in JSON_DATA['content']:
    x['CronExpression'] = cron_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, `Report_JSON` is loaded as a `list` type in Python (JSON data can be interpreted by Python as either a `list`, if it is surrounded by `[]` square brackets, or a `dict` if it is surrounded by `{}` curly brackets).

When you call `Report_JSON.append()`, it will append a new item to the list. You are creating a new dictionary with a single key-value pair (`CronExpression`) and adding it to the list, which is why the two dictionaries are side-by-side.

What you should do instead is get the first item in the `Report_JSON` list, which is the dictionary; then ask for the value corresponding to the `content` key, which will be a list; then ask for the first item in that list, which will be the dictionary you want to modify (with keys `id`, `name`, `description`, etc.)

Modify that dictionary, then put it back in the list. Here's the code that will do that:

```
# Get first item in Report_JSON list
content_dict = Report_JSON[0]

# Get the value corresponding to the 'content' key, which is a list
content_value = content_dict['content']

# Get the first item in the list, which is the dict you want to modify
dict_to_modify = content_value[0]

# Now add your new key-value pair
dict_to_modify['CronExpression'] = "0 1,30 4,5,6,7 ..."
```

Or, to do it in one shot:

```
Report_JSON[0]['content'][0]['CronExpression'] = "0 1,30 4,5,6,7 ..."
```

**UPDATE:** If the "content" list has multiple items, you can iterate over each item in that list:

```
for content_dict in Report_JSON[0]['content']:
    content_dict['CronExpression'] = "0 1,30 4,5,6,7 ..."
```

which will result in something like this:

```
             [
               {
                  "content": [
                     {
                       "id": 001,
                       "name": "Sample_Name",
                       "description": "Sample_description",
                       "status": "STARTED",
                       "source": null,
                       "user": "username",
                       "CronExpression": "0 1,30 4,5,6,7 ..."
                     },

                     {
                       "id": 002,
                       "name": "Another_Sample_Name",
                       "description": "Another_sample_description",
                       "status": "STARTED",
                       "source": null,
                       "user": "another_username",
                       "CronExpression": "0 1,30 4,5,6,7 ..."
                     },
                   ]
                },
              ],
```

**UPDATE 2:** If you are not interested in keeping the original structure and you want to strip everything up to and including the "content" key, you can just do this to start off:

```
Report_JSON = Report_JSON[0]['content']
```

and `Report_JSON` is now just the inner "content" list.

Comment: Thats a great explanation. This worked too. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to click the green check mark to accept this as the answer, so people know it solved your problem. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)